# realloc homework help

Tags: c, realloc

For an assignment, part of what I have to do involves the use of `malloc` and `realloc`. I first create a 2D array of chars, the dimensions being the number of lines and the number of characters. I then use `malloc` to allocate enough memory to store input from some file. Using `fgets` I read one line in at a time, and store it in the array. This part works fine (or so I think). The problem comes in when I try to reallocate memory for more lines if need be. The program flow is supposed to be like this:

Create a character array of 50 lines, with 80 characters per line (working)

Use `fgets` to read one line at a time and save it to the array (working)

When 50 lines have been read, reallocate the array to allow for 100 lines (not working)

Keep reallocating as need be (not working)

This is what I have so far (the core of it at least, I omitted irrelevant code):

```
#define NUMBER_OF_LINES 50
#define CHARACTERS_PER_LINE 80

FILE *inputFile = fopen("some.text", "r");

char **lines;
lines = malloc(NUMBER_OF_LINES * sizeof(*lines));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++)
  *(lines+i) = malloc(CHARACTERS_PER_LINE * sizeof(char));

int linesRemaining = NUMBER_OF_LINES;
int reallocCount = 1;
i = 0;
while (!feof(inputFile)) {
  if (!linesRemaining) {
    reallocCount++;
    lines = realloc(lines, (NUM_OF_LINES * reallocCount) * sizeof(*lines));
    linesRemaining = NUM_OF_LINES;
  }
  fgets(*(lines+i), CHARS_PER_LINE, inputFile);
  i++;
  linesRemaining--;
}
```

My gut tells me the problem is with the `realloc`, so I'll explain what I *think* it's doing.

```
realloc(lines, (NUM_OF_LINES * reallocCount) * sizeof(*lines));
```

The first argument, `lines`, is the pointer I would like to reallocate a certain amount of memory. `NUM_OF_LINES` is the amount I would like to increase the size by. I multiply this by `reallocLinesCount`, which is a counter that keeps track of how many sets of 50 lines I ought to have. The `sizeof(*lines)` part is the size of a pointer to a `char`.

Thank you for reading and any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: thank you all for the responses; I do not have time right now to read all of the answers right now, but all of your answers will be more thoroughly read and understood once this imminent deadline has passed :D

Comment: Pre-/post-increment/decrement trip up many a novice C programmer; write the code without them, then introduce them as you gain experience.

Comment: I'll never understand this strange fetish teachers have to teach students to statically allocate arrays with a specific length. It's like they're TRYING to raise the next generation of easily hacked software writers..

Comment: Edited to not have pre-/post-increment/decrements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My motto is: "say what you mean". In your case, you MEAN to enlarge your array when it's not big enough to hold your data.

```
FILE *in;      // you fill this in
int nlines=50; // initial value
char **buffer=malloc(nlines * sizeof *buffer);
int i=0;

for(int i=0; !feof(in); ++i)
{
  if(i>=nlines)
    buffer=realloc(buffer, (nlines+=50)*sizeof *buffer);

  buffer[i]=malloc(80);
  fgets(buffer[i], 80, in);
}
```

Comment: This works thank you! I've done a lot of Java programming, where assignments evaluate to true or false, I like how you can treat (nlines+=50) as an int. Clever use of !feof(in) as the conditional in the for loop.

Comment: well, this kind of coding is not acceptable by many experienced programmer (i'm not experienced enough ;)). i personally like `!feof(in)` but doesn't like `(nlines+=50)*sizeof *buffer`.

Comment: @Donotalo, in general, try speaking only for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`realloc()` will often find out that there is not enough available room to expand the existing array in-place; in that case, it will create an *entirely new* array of the specified size, copy the contents of the old array to the new one, deallocate the old array, and return a pointer to the new one. So you should write

```
char **oldLines = lines;
lines = realloc(...);
```

(the purpose of `oldLines` is to keep the original pointer in case `realloc()` runs out of memory and returns `NULL`, as per @Brian L's tip).

Comment: What exactly is happening (how do you see that it doesn't work)? Does it crash (where, and with what message), or does it produce garbled results (what results)?

Comment: You should never assign the results of realloc() directly to the variable you are reallocating. If the call to realloc() fails, you will no longer have a pointer to the previously allocated memory. If you're just going to abort your program on a realloc failure, maybe it doesn't matter. But it seems like a good habit to use Donotalo's method below.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should realloc:

```
char **new_lines = realloc(lines, (NUM_OF_LINES * ++reallocLinesCount) * sizeof(*lines));
if (new_lines)
{
    lines = new_lines;
}
else
{
    // Memory allocation fails. Do some error handling.
}
```

Read [realloc reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) for details.

**EDIT**

You need more allocation for each new lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating more pointers to lines but not the lines themselves. It is in your code at the beginning:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++)
   *(lines+i) = malloc(CHARACTERS_PER_LINE * sizeof(char));
```

So after you allocated your number of lines for each line you allocate the space for the line itself. You forgot to do this for the new lines when you reallocate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first [see how `realloc()` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331221/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-realloc).  It returns a pointer to *new*
memory on success, and `NULL` on failure.  On failure, it doesn't
touch the old memory, and on success, it `free()`'s it, after copying
your data to the new place.

So, the way to use `realloc()` safely is:

```
/* allocate memory using malloc() */
ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr);
/* make sure malloc succeeded */
...
/* call realloc() */
new_ptr = realloc(ptr, M * sizeof *new_ptr);
/* see if it succeeded */
if (new_ptr) {
    /* okay, we can set ptr */
    ptr = new_ptr;
} else {
    /* realloc failed, old pointer still valid */
}
```

So, the first thing is that you are using `realloc()` incorrectly.
You should *never* say `x = realloc(x, ...);`, because if `realloc()`
fails, you assign `x` to `NULL`, and the old memory is lost.  This is
a memory leak.

Now, on to your problem.  Let's say you have successfully read
`NUMBER_OF_LINES` lines.  Now you want to make room for an additional
`NUMBER_OF_LINES` lines.  You would do:

```
char **new_lines = realloc(lines, NUMBER_OF_LINES*reallocCount*sizeof *new_lines);
if (new_lines) {
    lines = new_lines;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed!\n");
    return;
}

/* Now, lines[NUMBER_OF_LINES] to lines[2*NUMBER_OF_LINES-1] are
 * available to point someplace useful.  They don't point anywhere
 * useful yet.  We have to allocate memory for them, just like earlier */

start = NUMBER_OF_LINES*reallocCount;
for (i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; ++i) {
    /* You weren't allocating memory here, and were writing to
     * lines[0] through lines[NUMBER_OF_LINES-1], which is not what
     * you want. */
    lines[start+i] = malloc(CHARS_PER_LINE * sizeof *lines[start+i]);
    /* check the result of malloc here */
}
fgets(lines[start+i], CHARS_PER_LINE, inputFile);
```

One final note:  it's [almost always wrong](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html) to use `while (!feof(fp))`
to read lines from a file.