# Why should I use void * instead of explicit pointer type in sizeof()?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I read this comment under a StackOverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331268/17342809):

> Memory allocation requests should be made as type-independent as possible: no cast on the result of memory allocation function and no type names under the sizeof. The strange habit of using type names under sizeof in malloc requests (and such) has long ago earned its place in the garbage bin of C programming. Type names belong in declarations. If it is not a declaration, type names are not allowed (as much as possible).

I can understand why it is bad to cast the result of `malloc()` (by reading this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/17342809). However, it looks to me that using type names in sizeof() (e.g. `sizeof(int *)` instead of `sizeof(void *)`) in memory allocation should make your code easier to read, as the reader could immediately see what you intend to use this memory for.
Can someone explain me why it is a bad habit to use explicit pointer types in `malloc(sizeof(type *))`?

Comment: `sizeof(int*)` if you intent to store `int*`s in the memory seems obviously better than `sizeof(void*)`. There isn't even a general guarantee that these two sizes are the same. But that isn't what the comment you quote is suggesting anyway. The comment you quote is criticizing the answer you link where this is suggested. The comment is saying that the use in the question itself is the preferred one, e.g. `char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 50);`: The type is mentioned only in the declaration of `ptr`.

Comment: What they mean to say is instead of `int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int))` do `int *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo)`.  The latter is a purely mechanical, and you don't repeat the type which may change.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the context of the comment. Thank you both!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `sizeof` with the type prefer to use the variable name.  For example instead of:

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

prefer the idiom:

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
```

This means you are not repeating (DRY) the type of the declaration which may change independently.  If the type changes in best case it doesn't matter or you allocate too much memory, worst case you allocate too little memory which cause corrupting due to a change that is possible far away (say, in a separate header file).

The other thing I find convenient is that it's a purely mechanical transformation (as in I don't have to think about it): `sizeof` followed by `*` and the name of the variable.  This eliminates the class of errors where the wrong type is used.

It's usually shorter to write.

Parenthesis are required when you pass a type of `sizeof` but not if you pass a variable.  `sizeof` binds the way you expect so `sizeof *foo * 42` would allocate space for 42 `int`s as expected.

Comment: Not only is it shorter to write, but it also avoids frequent errors when choosing the type

Comment: @dalfaB Thanks.  Reordered and expanded on that point.

Comment: This idiom is also good for later development or maintenance when types may change.

Comment: @adabsurdum Isn't "which may change independently" covering that?  As in, I am happy to clarify it.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I missed that bit.